# SSE or Websockets or AJAX - Server Load

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, ajax, websocket

I'm a beginner/intermediate programmer and this is my first post.

I've started a business that is booming at this point.
I pretty much learned PHP, Javascript and MYSQL while building this business and now, a year later, I'm at the point of redoing it all because of messy / poor code.

The problem I have (if it even is a problem) is the amount of AJAX requests we send, and the potential load its putting on the server.
I've got 80 tablets and 20-40 phones sending AJAX request every 30-60 seconds, that's not including our actual customers that are using out site/webapp.

Our tablets/phones are sending a request every 60 seconds to retrieve all activate orders. (It echo's out the data regardless of change --- and currently I'm actually echo'ing full div's and markup, which obviously I will change so that the client side deals with that).

I've been looking into Server Side events because we'd like to have more LIVE like updates, but I don't quite understand how to trigger a send event and it actually being more efficient.

From my research the way I'd have to do it is check the database every so many seconds to see if data changed (if the data didn't change it would have to hold current data in memory to compare with new data in the next loop).

Or do I just send ajax request every 10 seconds? What is more efficient/scalable? Do I need to switch to node.js for server side? (I do like the simplicity of PHP)

Or maybe websocket? I don't know near enough about it.

We've got a Quad core Xeon VPS
CPU seems to be mostly at 10-20% usage with occasional spikes to 80% usage during busy times.
Our CPU load sits around 2.5 - 3.5 for 15 minute average but I have seen 7-8 occasionally.

Honestly, I don't understand enough to make any decisions so I'm hoping for some input/advice.

Preach to me... and go!

Comment: Greetings and Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a community dedicated to programming related topics. Kindly read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. For recommendations on technologies or architectures visit https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

use websockets for broadcasting and REDIS for caching data. it is best to take Laravel - everything is already there.